# Exchange Server: How to expand distributed list to get all the members

Tags: python-3.x, exchange-server, exchangewebservices, ews-managed-api

We are building client for exchange server using python3.X as a language.

We found an existing library exchangelib, to perform all the basics operations including move, copy, delete etc email.

However we have an additional requirement to expand distributed list to get all the members of same.
Unfortunately this feature is not available in library.

Open Issue: https://github.com/ecederstrand/exchangelib/issues/93

Is there an alternate way to achieve same using web services provided by exchange.
If so any help on any relevant link will be of great help.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you want to stay with Python3, then I think actually implementing issue #93 will get you there with the least effort. All the building blocks are available in exchangelib. I'll happily provide guidance in the issue tracker to get you going, and ultimately merge a working implementation.

Comment: If you want to see a C# answer for this, take a look at it here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/71518937/8644294

Answer (score 2):

As requested:

How to expand a distribution group by using the EWS Managed API or EWS in Exchange example:

```
private static void ExpandDistributionLists(ExchangeService service)
{
     // Return the expanded group.
     ExpandGroupResults myGroupMembers = service.ExpandGroup("Group1@contoso.com");

     // Display the group members.
     foreach (EmailAddress address in myGroupMembers.Members)
     {
         Console.WriteLine("Email Address: {0}", address);
     }
}
```

*source [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn629392(v=exchg.150).aspx) or [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/hh532557(v=exchg.80).aspx)*